# How to implement custom method and use it with query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and I have the business rule: "Foo is ready if all their Bar children are ready" and in a use case I need to get all Foo that are ready so I'm trying to do the following query:

```
Session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.is_ready())
```

But I'm getting exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 185, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.comparator, key)
AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute 'all'
```

**models**

```
class Foo(Base):
    bars = relationship(Bar, lazy = "dynamic")
    @classmethod
    def is_ready(self):
        return len(self.bar.all()) == len(self.bars.filter(Bar.status == "ready"))

class Bar(Base):
    status = Column(String)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))
```

What am I doing wrong? I really need to implement a method Foo.is_ready() since the business rule would be more complex in the future so it is important encapsulate that behavior in order to reutilize later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because `self` in `classmethod` is the class itself, i.e. `Foo`. (This is why conventionally it is named `cls` instead of `self`.) Of course `Foo.bars` does not have `.all()`, because `Foo.bars` is the relationship itself, not a `Query` object.

What is the correct way to write this? In these scenarios, it is helpful to remove yourself from the magic of SQLAlchemy and think about the SQL that you need to write. An easy way is to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM bar
  WHERE bar.foo_id = foo.id AND bar.status != 'ready'
);
```

Or a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id AND bar.status != 'ready'
WHERE bar.id IS NULL;
```

Armed with this, it's easy to now write your `is_ready`:

```
class Foo(Base):
    @classmethod
    def is_ready(cls):
        return ~exists(select([Bar.id]).where(and_(Bar.foo_id == cls.id, Bar.status != "ready")))

session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.is_ready())
```

You can even turn it into a `hybrid_property`:

```
class Foo(Base):
    @hybrid_property
    def is_ready(self):
        return all(bar.status == "ready" for bar in self.bars)

    @is_ready.expression
    def is_ready(cls):
        bar = Bar.__table__
        return ~exists(select([Bar.id]).where(and_(Bar.foo_id == cls.id, Bar.status != "ready")))

session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.is_ready)
```

The `JOIN` is tricky to express using a `classmethod` or a `hybrid_property` like this, so one trick you can use is [`.with_transformation`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_transformation):

```
class Foo(Base):
    @classmethod
    def is_ready(cls):
        def _transformer(query):
            return query.join(Bar, and_(Foo.id == Bar.foo_id, Bar.status != "ready")).filter(Bar.id.is_(None))
        return _transformer

session.query(Foo).with_transformation(Foo.is_ready())
```

Comment: It works great! But I have another question. Why `is_ready(self)` is `@hybrid_property`? It could be a regular property `@property` and it would works great too if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Overflow012 A `hybrid_property` works on both instances and the class, so you can do both `Foo.is_ready` as a filter (using columns on the table), as well as `foo.is_ready` on an instance of the class (using attributes and relationships loaded in memory).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `bar` attribute, but `bars`. Try to use `hybrid_property` instead of `classmethod`. Code below, but I have not tested it.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Foo(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def is_ready(self):
        return self.bars.count() == self.bars.filter_by(status="ready").count()

class Bar(Base): 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = Column(String)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))
    foo = relationship(Foo, back_ref=back_ref("bars", lazy="dynamic"))
```